# Error While Swagger 2.0:(Patchable) responce.description is mandatory - While importing Swagger in Postman

Tags: json, swagger, postman, soapui

I am trying to migrate my Soap UI(Version 5.4) Project to Postman(Version 7.23.0), i have Exported swagger document from Soap UI project . Swagger got created but when i am trying to import same in Postman One error is Coming " Error While Swagger 2.0:(Patchable) responce.description is mandatory ".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MElHu.png)PleLx.png

Soap UI Version : 5.4
Postman : 7.23.0
Swagger Version : 2.0
API Version : 1.0

Answer (score 1):

You can downgrade postman version to 7.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try older version for postman.
https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman_pro/managing_postman_pro/migrating_to_v7/#download-latest-postman-v6-app 4.1k

ps:
  I have the same problem，but i switched the version. It is ok